# Where exactly is Yamada Castle in Okinawa?

Tags: japan, where-on-earth, architecture, okinawa, ruins

I've already visited [the one restored castle in Okinawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuri_Castle) and Wikipedia tells me there are several other ruined castles here on the main island.

But one castle is mentioned several times yet I cannot find its whereabouts, it is called [Yamada Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamada_Castle).

Wikipedia does not give latitude and longitude, Wikivoyage doesn't mention it, Google Maps doesn't find it. I've also tried OpenStreetMap and [the official site](http://www.vill.onna.okinawa.jp/) of [the nearest town or village in Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onna,_Okinawa), all to no avail.

It is mentioned that [Zakimi Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakimi_Castle) was build using materials from Yamada Castle, yet it is mentioned in several places that some ruins remain, so not everything was taken. In any case I'm interested in the location and surroundings even if there's not a lot to see.

As I'm thinking of hitchhiking north with my tent I'd be keen to find it as it's now the most mysterious one for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [blog post](http://www.gusukumichi.com/gusuku/yamada.html) about it, including a pointer to the location on [map.goo.ne.jp](http://map.goo.ne.jp/map.php?MAP=E127.47.8.62N26.25.28.063&MT=%B2%AD%C6%EC%B8%A9%B9%F1%C6%AC%B7%B4%B2%B8%C7%BC%C2%BC%BB%B3%C5%C4&ZM=8).  As you can see, it's hard to find and there's barely anything there aside from a few overgrown stone walls.  The last couple of photos are of a shrine along the way, not the ruins.

Comment: We actually saw a sign on the side of the road saying "Site of Yamada Castle" as we were driving south on Route 58 yesterday afternoon. Unfortunately we were in traffic so I couldn't get a photo of figure out exactly where we were. But at least the area is signposted.

Comment: How about the coordinates? Wikipedia gives 26°25′54″N 127°46′57″E as coordinates, but Google Maps Satellite shows at that point a house that does not match the description of the blog post. Nearby there are 3 suspect artifacts but difficult to say which one was Yamada Castle.